# Split one column into two columns based on the row is odd or even

Tags: excel

I am currently looking for a way in which I can split a column in excel into two column. 
The way I want to split is all data in the odd rows (1,3,5,…) should be in column A and all the data in the even rows (0,2,4,6,…) should be in column B…  how can this be done in excel, without having me to create the columns, and fill them up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,2*ROW()-1)
```

and copy downward and in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,2*ROW())
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or one formula in B1:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+COLUMN(A:A))
```

Copy/drag over one column and down till you run out of data.

[image]

Comment: clever!____________________